# How to overcome writing over a file C#

Tags: c#

EDIT: Add method where error actually occurs...

I am opening an image and I want to be able to overwrite the original file as modification happens. I tryed both of the methods [here](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=814675)

```
public ImgPro(String Path)
{
    Bitmap bt1 = new Bitmap(Path);
    Bitmap bt2 = new Bitmap(bt1.Width, bt1.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    var imgRec = new Rectangle(0, 0, bt1.Width, bt1.Height);
    Graphics bt2G = Graphics.FromImage(bt2);
    bt2G.DrawImage(bt1, imgRec);
    bt1.Dispose();
    this.bitmap = bt2;
}
```

And

```
public ImgPro(String Path)
{
    Bitmap bt1 = new Bitmap(Path);
    Bitmap bt2 = new Bitmap(bt1.Width, bt1.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    var imgRec = new Rectangle(0, 0, bt1.Width, bt1.Height);
    BitmapData bt1Data = bt1.LockBits(imgRec, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    BitmapData bt2Data = bt2.LockBits(imgRec, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

    // Create data array to hold bmpSource pixel data
    int numBytes = bt1Data.Stride * (int)bt1.Height;
    var srcData = new byte[numBytes];
    var destData = new byte[numBytes];

    Marshal.Copy(bt1Data.Scan0, srcData, 0, numBytes);
    Array.Copy(srcData, destData, srcData.Length);
    Marshal.Copy(destData, 0, bt2Data.Scan0, numBytes);

    bt1.UnlockBits(bt1Data); bt2.UnlockBits(bt2Data);
    bt1.Dispose();
    this.bitmap = bt2;
}
```

But both options failed when I went to save the file I got this error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

For this method:

```
public void Save(string filename)
{
     bitmap.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Comment: I'll never ever understand why SO users post code that *omits* the actual code that fails.

Comment: Edited with error location

Comment: Please use `using` statments on all `IDisposeable` objects you create and do not keep. You never dispose `bt2G` in your first snippit and if a execption is ever thrown the items you explicitly called `.Dispose()` on will never be disposed. The parts of .NET that rely on the GDI+ subsystem of windows (`Bitmap` and `Graphics`) is one area that can really get messed up if you forget to dispose of your objects. You will start to get `OutOfMemoryException`s when you still have plenty of memory left (GDI+ throws a `OutOfMemoryException` when it has run out of Handles and can not create one).

Comment: Thanks I am fairly new to C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Bitmap` locks the underlying stream, you could copy the file contents to a `MemoryStream` and base the `Bitmap` on that instead. This should prevent the file from being locked:

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Path);
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes)) // Don't dispose this until you're done with your Bitmap 
{
    Bitmap bt1 = new Bitmap(stream);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I added your changes to my method as well as `stream.Dispose();` at the end of the using and the error persists. I am using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1 if that is helpful.

Comment: Are you sure this relates to the fact that you're overwriting a file and not just to an error when saving the bitmap anywhere?

Comment: I can change the file name and save just fine so I am certain.

Comment: Just FYI: you don't need to do `stream.Dispose()` at the end of an `using` block... the `using` block does that for you.

Comment: Is `Path` an absolute path? Or is it possible that something *else* has the file locked? Process Explorer is a good tool for searching for file handles.

Comment: On reread of my code I found a spot I had not switched to using from the unlocked image and then reverted back to old version without this code but needed it so thanks!!!!